# How do I resize an existing image (not create a new copy

Tags: php

Everything I can find online about re-sizing an existing image with PHP seems to be about taking an existing image and creating a resized thumbnail (unless I'm missing something).  I already have the existing image on the server and i want THAT image (not a copy of that image) to be re sized.  I want the quality to be decent so I'm thinking: imagecopyresized
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

This is what I tried:

```
imagecopyresampled($sourceImageFilePath, $sourceImageFilePath, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizedWidth, $resizedHeight, $origWidth, $origHeight);
```

but I get a supplied argument is not a valid Image resource error.

I know if I was creating a new resized image from the existing I would need this:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($resizedWidth, $resizedHeight);
```

But I dont want to create NEW image but resize an existing one.

Thoughts?

Comment: resize it then save it with same old image name

Comment: Isn't that what this should do: imagecopyresampled($sourceImageFilePath, $sourceImageFilePath, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizedWidth, $resizedHeight, $origWidth, $origHeight);

Comment: if you get the file uploaded by a user, why not just use $_FILES array as source, and the final location as target ? the tmp image is deleted on the end of the request automaticly.

besides that, you can use different functions to read in and write out the image, so the target can also be the source.

Comment: @ChrisCummings nope, as it reads and writes at the same time... it cant open the file for writing as long as it is open.

Comment: Also, just to point out that ImageMagick (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is a really good PHP image manipulation library.  I suggest taking a look.

Comment: File may have been uploaded previously (days, weeks) so the tmp wouldn't exist

Comment: OK so then HOW exactly do I do it?  Save as the same name, I mean...how do I do that?

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I think my problem is that I'm trying to work with filenames and not resources.  When I use a resource I can create my own temp copy because nothing is saved until I output it all, right?

Comment: @ChrisCummings Yes, your last comment is true. You should create image resource from the source file, resize it, and then save this resource using same filename